# How to fetch records in form of array instead of String Using SOAP webservice(xmlparsing)

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, xml-parsing

I have use following code for call soap web service, Here in `string` i get all values but i want it in array to display in tableview.How to store this in array please suggest way.Or how to fetch records in form of array?

[From where i have get code](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/622376/iOS-Soap-Webservice-Calling-and-Parsing-the-Resp)

```
    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"GetCenterResult"])
        {
            if(!soapResults)
            {
                soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            }
            recordResults = TRUE;
        }
    }
    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
    {
        if( recordResults )
        {
            NSLog(@"-%@",string);

            [soapResults appendString: string];
            mutabl_arr = [soapResults copy];
           NSLog(@"%@",mutabl_arr);


          //  NSLog(@"First make: %@", [mutabl_arr objectAtIndex:0]);
        }

    }
    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {

        if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"GetCenterResult"])
        {
            recordResults = FALSE;
            abc1.text = soapResults;


            NSLog(@"Data from XML file  ==  %@",soapResults);
            //mutabl_arr = [soapResults copy];
            NSLog(@"Arreay%@",mutabl_arr);



            }


  }
```

Error `__NSCFString` Comes if i will trying to access mutabl_arr using its index.

Comment: What does the error (`err`) tell you?

Comment: @Avi No but is there any way to print ns data with nslog or etc.?

Comment: @Avi Actually i cant store value of NSData's in NsArray?

Comment: First i would make sure that data is not null, than make sure that data is JSON :)

Comment: @trojanfoe I have use this for placing in Nsarray &err really purpose for it i don't know i have make this code with help of some online codes.

Comment: ok quick question is your json a dict? can you check what this will print `id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&err];`

Comment: What's the value of `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]`?

Comment: Hey @sken3r.MI as you have asked, my webservice is created in soap so now is it possible to call it through json or i have to start working on SOAP?

Comment: Ok so your nsdata is not JSON :). As i remember SOAP is some kind of XML with envelope and things, so yes definitely you need to use SOAP, i had once worked with it, but i cant remember the tool i used, you will have to translate the WSDL to ObjC and use it in order to send and receive request

Comment: You can try this for parsing xml to dictionary [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053792/xml-to-dictionary-parsing-using-xml-reader][1]

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaSiddiqui it is not works for insert operation

Comment: How can i call soap webservice through json code?